# WPF treeview. Two-way data binding with list and textbox. How find element in list?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have list of my custom class. I get this class by reading a file and save it in list. Thereafter I display this list as treeview whith textbox to be able to change fields in list. I can get item treeview (with filds name and nodes) but how i can find this element in list?

so my code

`<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Slots}" DataType="{x:Type VM:ViewModelFrame}">
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding FrameName}"/>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Value}" DataType="{x:Type VM:ViewModelSlot}">
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding SlotName}"/>
                            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type VM:ViewModelSlotValue}">
                                    <TextBox Text="{Binding SlotValue}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</TreeView.ItemTemplate>`

I have a list Frame (my class). In it I have list and Slot have value. All of it user have to change. So i want if user change for example value in second Frame second Slot in list it change in list.

Comment: Can you provide some code so we can help you? What objects placed in list and what objects placed in a tree view?

Comment: A common approach is to work with selecteditem.  Use a behavior so you can bind this to a property in a viewmodel. Then the selecteditem object is the object you need.